# How to create multiple line charts from a single component in React

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I am trying to create multiple line charts from a single component in react and seem to be getting lost a big.

My API is giving me back data that looks like this.

```
[
 {
        "price": 6500,
        "expiration": "10",
        "bid": 86.44,
        "mark": 89.74,
        "ask": 95.94,
        "dif": -0.01575
      },
      {
        "price": 6750,
        "expiration": "10",
        "bid": 74.09,
        "mark": 78.77,
        "ask": 82.52,
        "dif": -0.02023
      },
      {
        "price": 7000,
        "expiration": "20",
        "bid": 69.28,
        "mark": 70.67,
        "ask": 74.62,
        "dif": -0.03171
      },
      {
        "price": 7250,
        "expiration": "20",
        "bid": 68.06,
        "mark": 67.44,
        "ask": 71.08,
        "dif": -0.06388
      }
]
```

What I am trying to do is to create a component that will take this data and map it to two separate line charts using Chart.Js.

Each chart should be broken out by `expiration`.  With the X-axis being price and the Y-axis is supposed to be mark.  I have found a good example implementing close to what I want to do here -->  [How to map multiple charts with chart.js in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56948468/how-to-map-multiple-charts-with-chart-js-in-react)

But I want to create 2 charts from this data. Where the charts are grouped by Expiration.   I am not sure what I am missing from the example above that I would need to change to do this. Any help would be amazing.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Line } from "react-chartjs-2";
import axios from "axios";

export default class Chart extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      chartData: [],
      data: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
   fetch(API, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                body: JSON.stringify({query: query}),
            })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (res)=>{
        const x = res.data;
        let chartData = [];
        x.forEach(element => {
          chartData.push({
            labels: element.expiration,
            datasets: [{ data: element.price}]
          });
        });
        this.setState({ chartData });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="chart">
        {this.state.chartData.map((n, index) => {
          return <Line key={index} data={n} />;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what's 'element.s' in 'datasets: [{ data: element.s}]'? there's no such property?

Comment: Sorry - its is suppposed to be price.... I just update that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to map multiple charts with chart.js in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56948468/how-to-map-multiple-charts-with-chart-js-in-react)

Comment: No, I want to break each graph out by Expiration as the Title. X being price, Y being Mark. I think I may need to reshape my response object by not sure how.

Comment: you should be more specific on your question title. try to write something about your problem.

Comment: Thanks - updated.

Comment: basically I want the Title of the Chart to be - The expiration. And then map the price and mark as the axis